# Starting application on start-up, using the wrong path to load

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, registry

I am using registry key to set my application to load on Windows Startup(after a user login).
My Code:

```
RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegKey = RegKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
RegKey.SetValue("AppName", "\"" + @"C:\Users\Name\Desktop" + "\"");
RegKey.Close();
```

So with this code, my application load at startup, however the working directory is

> C:\Windows\System32

Does anyone know why ?

This does not work for me because that program needs couple of files within the same directory as that one to operate. If the program loaded on my chosen directory("C:\Users\Name\Desktop") then the problem would not exist.

Anyone has any suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()` can be used to set your working directory when the app starts. EXE path can be retrieved using `Application.ExecutablePath`.

Put them together:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath);
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(fi.DirectoryName);
```

Comment: Hi, Please check my answer. Is that what you meant ? I was a little confused on what you meant but your idea gave me the idea to read the registry to get the directory path and set that as the currentpath.
thanks (:

Comment: I think using Application.ExecutablePath is cleaner than getting a value from registry :P

Comment: wow, your right. It did work.
Thanks! I'm voting it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a cheap trick on how to accomplish this.
When your application starts up, Read the registry again to get your application's start-up path(the one you intended).
For example: Appl1 has a startup path of "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\App1.exe".

Once you read the registry for that path, set that as current directory.
Something like this:

```
        RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
        RegKey = RegKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", false);
        string Path = RegKey.GetValue("App1.exe").ToString();
        Path = Path.Replace(@"\App1.exe"", ""); // Now it's a valid directory.
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path);
```

This worked for me but if anyone has a better method, I would love to hear them.

Comment: Why circle back around to the registry instead of adding a line in your entry point that just sets the current directory. Not very clean and prone to issues.